# StoreKit in Xcode 8 and iOS 10 not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am using XCode version 2345.1 and I have a device with iOS 10.0.1. The app was working with in-app purchases in iOS 9, now I cannot perform that functionality.

On debugging, I got 'SKErrorUnknown' in one device whilst in another I got 'SKErrorClientInvalid'. The second one is because the account i am using to buy is for US store while the app is of Indian store.

When I change the store in App Store, following is shown :- 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be your app is enabled only for other location, test user was localised for other - and with this setup does not work.

You should enabled the app for USA and created a test user localised in USA and it seems to work (no code change at all). And I think that proves that the code is ok, just the apple sandbox has some problems with non USA test users.

Comment: I found the problem ,the account i was using is admin account. I added that account to the external testers but wasnot able to add as a sandbox tester. There fore, I was facing those problems. Thanks anyways